# OSSEC not detecting deleted files?

Tags: pci-dss, ids, configuration, centos, windows-server

I have configured 3 VMs: ossec server and two agents in CentOS 6 and Windows 2k8 R2. I have completed the setup and FIM and Log Management works smoothly. It also reports the new files. However, it doesn't detect (or I would rather say reports) the deleted files. I have searched the Google group and didn't find any answer. I have checked the rules it is available and rule is included in the config files.

PS most of the setting as default as initially installed.

```
<syscheck> 
    <!-- Frequency that syscheck is executed - default to every 22 hours -->    
    <frequency>300</frequency> 
    <!-- Directories to check (perform all possible verifications) --> 
    <directories check_all="yes">/etc,/usr/bin,/usr/sbin</directories> 
    <directories check_all="yes">/bin,/sbin</directories> 
    <!-- Files/directories to ignore --> 
    <ignore>/etc/mtab</ignore> 
    <!-- Windows files to ignore --> 
    <ignore>C:\WINDOWS/System32/LogFiles</ignore> 
    <ignore>C:\WINDOWS/Debug</ignore> 
</syscheck>
```

config is include with the rules ossec_rule.xml where the rule defines as:

```
<rule id="553" level="7"> 
    <category>ossec</category> 
    <decoded_as>syscheck_deleted</decoded_as>   
    <description>File deleted. Unable to retrieve checksum.</description> 
    <group>syscheck,</group> 
</rule>
```

and this rule is included in the config file.

Comment: I don't have an answer but wanted to confirm deletes not showing up on both CentOS and Windows?

Comment: So it detects changes to files and creation of files but not deletion? Can you post the relevant configuration for syscheck in your conf file?

Comment: yes in the both system win 2k8 as well as cent os  the deleted file is not detected by the ossec.

Comment: <syscheck>
    <!-- Frequency that syscheck is executed - default to every 22 hours -->
    <frequency>300</frequency>

    <!-- Directories to check  (perform all possible verifications) -->
    <directories check_all="yes">/etc,/usr/bin,/usr/sbin</directories>
    <directories check_all="yes">/bin,/sbin</directories>

    <!-- Files/directories to ignore -->
    <ignore>/etc/mtab</ignore>

    <!-- Windows files to ignore -->
    <ignore>C:\WINDOWS/System32/LogFiles</ignore>
    <ignore>C:\WINDOWS/Debug</ignore>
  </syscheck>

Comment: sorry i am new to this form and i cannot figure out which tab to use to post the codes
 config is include with the ruls ossec_rule.xml wehre the rule defines as : <rule id="553" level="7"> <category>ossec</category> <decoded_as>syscheck_deleted</decoded_as> <description>File deleted. Unable to retrieve checksum.</description> <group>syscheck,</group> </rule> and this rule is included in the config file